# How to sum with weeknum condition in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

i have data and want to sum it with weeknum in every name condition, but i can't do that it always error parse or empty value.
this my query

```
=query(A1:D8,"select sum(D) where D='"&G2&"' and B='"&H1&"' label sum(D)'' ")
```

---

```
=query(A1:D8,"select sum(D) where D='"&G2&"' and weeknum(A)=weeknum('"&H1&"') label sum(D)'' ")
```

[image]

this my link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHnu-IrFQuh7scbtoQriB_7frhvLUYfO9gIX2yqiXBY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Format code as code.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(A:D, "select C,sum(D) where B = "&H1&" group by C label sum(D)''", 0)
```

[image]

if you want 0 values use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")), 
 QUERY(A:D, "select C,sum(D) where B = "&H1&" group by C label sum(D)''", 0), 2, 0), 0)})
```

[image]

Comment: hello @player0  how about if i have 2 column to sum, i have add sum(E) but it doesn't work =ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")), 
 QUERY(A:E, "select C,sum(D),sum(E) where B = "&H1&" group by C label sum(D)'',sum(E)''", 0), 2, 0), 0)})

Comment: @produksiktg can you share a copy of your sheet?